# Porque que quando coloco o componente "JComboBox" da Swing meu programa fica com essa aparência?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, awt

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

código que usei

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBox extends JFrame{

JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<String>();

public ComboBox(){
    add(combo);
    combo.addItem("Brasil");
    combo.addItem("Argentina");

    setTitle("Título da Janela");
    setSize(400,300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new ComboBox();

   }

}
```

desculpa se a pergunta foi idiota, é que eu estava acompanhando aulas de java sobre swing e a aparência desse componente era diferente...ficava mais bonito, tem como eu arrumar isso?

Comment: Você tem q definir o layout do JFrame

Comment: tem como me dar um exemplo? sou bem leigo ainda ;-;

Answer (score 1):

Em java-swing, utilizandos os [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para organizarmos os componentes conforme a necessidade que tivermos, e quando não informamos nenhum, o JFrame por padrão utiliza o BorderLayout, que basicamente é um layout que organiza os componentes de forma automática, usando coordenadas, conforme a figura abaixo mostra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao adicionar o componente sem manusear o layout, ele é adicionado com a coordenada `BorderLayout.CENTER`, e conforme definição do próprio layout na documentação do java, o componente preencherá todo o espaço da área definida, conforme cada coordenada da figura acima, no caso da central, caso não tenha mais nada na tela, vai preencher ela completa.

Se não quer este comportamento, teste layouts diferentes, no link acima há uma lista deles e como cada um funciona.